# Symfony 4.4 - How to insert datas in 2 tables that are linked in one form

Tags: symfony4, symfony-forms

I have 2 tables "utilisateur" (user) and "pilote" (rider) that have a OneToOne relation.
When a user register, i want him to enter a mail / a password and a nickname which is his rider name. Mail and password goes into "utilisateur" and the nickname goes into "pilote". The mail and the nickname must both be unique.

What I have right now :

- I made my entities, "utilisateur" has a "pilote" attribute to make the relation.
  [Code of utilisateur Entity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/be8fx.png)
- I already have a register form (made with make:registration-form) which works.

What I dont get :

- How to add a nickname field in my registration form in order to create a "pilote" entity that should be then added to my "utilisateur" entity in my controller ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you just have to create 2 new objects of your entity and link them like this:

```
class TestController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @param Request $request
     * @param EntityManagerInterface $em
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index(
        Request $request,
        EntityManagerInterface $em
    )
    {
        // add searchForm
        $form = $this->createForm(YourForm::class);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        // Check Form
        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $formData = $form->getData();

            // @todo check for duplicates
            // you would have to check if Utilisateur/Pilote already exists and only then add,
            // if not you'll get duplicates
            $utilisateur = new Utilisateur($formData['mail'], $formData['password']); // create Utilisateur
            $utilisateur->setPilote(new Pilote($formData['nickname'])); // link Pilote
            $em->persist($utilisateur);
            $em->flush(); // commit your new User
            
            // add success flash
            $this->addFlash(sprintf("Utilisateur %s() created", $utilisateur->getMail));
        }

        return $this->render(
            'yourTemplate.html.twig',
            [
                'form' => $form->createView(),
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

Now you should see 2 new entries on your database

Comment: My problem was how to display them in the FormType, i could'nt find how to but anyway i changed the way i handled it so it is not a problem anymore. Thanks anyway

Comment: I've learned that it is best to keep a form as dumb as possible and keep the logic in the controller. Therefore the form can be made more reusable.